# Why, if I manage a user's Google Drive account, do requests post to my account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-drive-api

I don't understand why uploads I do to an account that isn't mine are posted to my account, where I also need to have the Google Drive API enabled for it to work...

Shouldn't it publish to the user account I manage and not mine?

[image]

Why if I am managing a user's Google Drive account for posting, deleting, etc., do the requests post to my account?

In other words, would each user whose account I manage consume the limit set by Google for the Google Drive API for my account?

In an example, if the user is already enabled to upload files to their account through the permissions they authorized me and decides to post a file to their account, where there are also 19,999 other users doing the same in their own authorized accounts. Would the quota of 20,000 requests per minute that Google set for my account be consumed?

Or is it 20,000 requests per minute for each token assigned to that user who owns the account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created a project up on google cloud console for your application. This project and your application are what is being deducted quota it has nothing to do with your personal user or that of your users.

As the owner of the project (denoted by the client id and client secret you are using) on google cloud console you can see what request are being made though your application into your project and the amount of quota the project it self has used across all the users.

If the user has granted your application permission to upload files via their account the quota will be used from your application.

There are two types of quotas though.  Project based quotas which are across your full project and users based quotas which are per user.

[image]

In the above example My project as a whole across all users can max a max of 10000 queries per minute.  It doesn't matter if i have one user or 1000 users across all users it can make a max of 10000 requests.

However each user who has authorized my project can make a max of 600 requests per minute.

Again these quotas are counted against my project not the user themselves.